# ‎"Responsible" Author? or "Corresponding" Author?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Is "Responsible Author" equal to "Corresponding Author", regarding the co-author who take the responsibility of  an academic article.

Comment: "The corresponding author is the one individual who takes primary responsibility for communication" [ICME](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html). They appear to be the same thing from this link but I did not read it all.

Comment: What did your dictionaries or search engines or depatmental style guides leave unclear, please? Broadly no, they are not the same, nor even similar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about academic definitions (jargon),  and as such would be better on Academia.SE.

Comment: These terms do not even belong to a jargon that would be readily understood by everyone within the academia; rather they belong to the jargon(s) that some publishing companies have recently introduced for their own purposes. In interactions with a particular publishing company, the terms have whatever meanings the company has chosen to give them; outside such a context their meanings are vague.

Answer (score 1):

"Corresponding Author" is  more common than "Responsible Author" in academic research papers. "Responsible Author" is a more general term and refers to the  "responsibility" of any author.